# 1048, "Column 'materials' cannot be null"

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a model with following fields. But my checkbox is not working.
models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    # dob = models.DateField(max_length=8)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phn_no = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    dept = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True)
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    materials = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

This is the user interface created for my form.
student.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" >
<!--    <script src="http://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>-->
    <script src="{% static 'js/a076d05399.js' %}"></script>
<!--    <meta name="description" content="{% block metadescription%} {% endblock %}">-->
<!--    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>-->
    <script>
var deptObject = {
  "Computer Science": ["MCA","BCA","MSc Computer Science", "BSc Computer Science"],
  "Commerce": ["Mcom", "Bcom", "BBA"]
}
window.onload = function() {
  var deptSel = document.getElementById("dept");
  var courseSel = document.getElementById("course");
  for (var x in deptObject) {
    deptSel.appendChild(new Option(x, x));
  }
  deptSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    courseSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in deptObject[this.value]) {
      courseSel.appendChild(new Option(deptObject[this.value][y], y));
    }
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card">
                    <h4 class="card-header text-center">Student Form</h4>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <form method="post" >
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><b>Name</b></label>
                                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger">
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "name" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><b>Age</b></label>
                                <input name="age" type="number" class="form-control">
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "age" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><b>Gender</b></label><br>
                                Male<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" >
                                Female<input name="gender" type="radio" value="Female">
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "gender" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><b>Phone Number</b></label>
                                <input name="phn_no" type="number" class="form-control">
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "phn_no" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><b>Email</b></label>
                                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control">
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "email" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><b>Address</b></label>
                                <input name="address" type="text" class="form-control">
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "address" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div>
                                <label><b>Department</b></label>
                                <select name="dept" id="dept">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Department</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <label><b>Course</b></label>
                                <select name="course" id="course">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select department first</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "dept" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label><b>Purpose</b></label>
                                <select name="purpose" id="purpose">
                                    <option value="Enquiry" selected="selected">Enquiry</option>
                                    <option value="Place Order" selected="selected">Place Order</option>
                                    <option value="Return" selected="selected">Return</option>
                                </select>
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "purpose" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <label><b>Materials Provided</b></label>
                                    <input name="materials1" type="checkbox" id="materials1"  value="NoteBook">
                                    <label for="materials1">NoteBook</label>
                                    <input name="materials2" type="checkbox" id="materials2"  value="Pencil">
                                    <label for="materials2">Pencil</label>
                                    <input name="materials3" type="checkbox" id="materials3"  value="TextBook">
                                    <label for="materials3">TextBook</label>
                                    <input name="materials4" type="checkbox" id="materials4"  value="Exam Paper">
                                    <label for="materials4">Exam Paper</label>
                                </fieldset>
                                {% if messages %}
                                {%for message in messages %}
                                {%if "address" in message.tags %}
                                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                                    <div class="form-control-feedback">{{message}}</div>
                                  </div>
                                {%endif%} {%endfor%} {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="mx-auto text-center">
                                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
        <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the function.
views.py

```
def student(request):
    student1=Student.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        # dob = request.POST.get('dob')
        age = request.POST.get('age')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        phn_no = request.POST.get('phn_no')
        dept = request.POST.get('dept')
        course = request.POST.get('course')
        purpose = request.POST.get('purpose')
        materials = request.POST.get('materials')
        student = Student(name=name,course=course,age=age,gender=gender,email=email,address=address,phn_no=phn_no,dept=dept,purpose=purpose,materials=materials)
        student.save()
    return render(request,'student.html',{'student1':student1})
```

When i click on the submit button, its showing me "IntegrityError at /student
(1048, "Column 'materials' cannot be null")".
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Well, the error tells you all you need. When you try to `.save()` the student then it complains because the `materials=materials` you pass it is None but `materials` is not a nullable column. I cannot see any form field called `materials` in your html, only materials1,2,3 and 4. You should either a) edit your student and db table so that they expect 4 different materials or b) you should edit your form so that you only return one or c) you should combine all four into one in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You might try making the `materials` field in the `Student` model nullable, and then run migration.

```py
class Student(models.Model):
   materials = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
```

Then, migrate using the following commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```